# SQL INSERT with an if statement

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a table called `notification`, with two columns:

- provider
- email

The values look like this:

- apple | apple@apple.com
- nbc | nbc@nbc.com
- nbc | me@me.com
- abc | abc@abc.com
- abc | me@me.com

For all providers that do not have the email `me@me.com`, I want to insert another row with the provider and the email `them@them.com`. For example, in the above query, the result of the `INSERT` statement would be: `INSERT INTO notification VALUES ('apple', 'them@them.com')`.

I have a table with thousands of rows like this, how would I write such an `INSERT` statement?

Comment: use t-sql - transact sql has conditional expressions to execute different statements based on logical expressions

Comment: Given your test data, wouldn't you also want to insert a row for abc?

Comment: The provider `abc` also lacks the email `me@me.com` (but does have `abc@me.com`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO notification
SELECT DISTINCT provider, 'them@them.com'
FROM notification
WHERE provider NOT IN
(SELECT DISTINCT provider
FROM notification
WHERE email = 'me@me.com')
```

Comment: `distinct` on the inner query is there, and it's better performance wise too (slightly) (compared to having distinct on the outer `select`)

Comment: This can insert duplicate rows (in this case for "abc").

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you're after:

```
insert into notification (provider, email)
select distinct provider, 'them@them.com'
from notification
where provider not in (
        select provider
        from notification
        where email like 'me@me.com'
    )
```

Comment: Nope. That would insert a new record for every record that wasn't like me@me.com, as opposed to one for each provider that doesn't have a me@me.com.

Comment: I deleted that nearly as fast as I posted it.